What is the advantage of using StringNVarcharType over StringType for mappings to columns of type NVARCHAR?
Hibernate seems to work equally well with columns of type NVARCHAR when using either StringNVarcharType or StringType for mapping.
Using StringType, which is the default, seems to offer some advantages. For example, portability – the same mapping would work well for PostgreSQL TEXT and SQL Server NVARCHAR, and SQL Server VARCHAR (with and without UTF8 collation).
In what situations would StringNVarcharType be preferred over StringType if the underlying column type is NVARCHAR?

I don't use hibernate. Does it create parameterised queries with the parameter datatype based around the StringType/StringNVarcharType distinction? If so and it uses a varchar parameter then this will only support the 256 characters of the code page in use. Conversely if it uses an nvarchar parameter when the underlying column is varchar this can prevent index seeks dependent on collation in use so you would want to make sure any such parameters match the column datatype

Using StringNVarcharType in application to VARCHAR is not supported - runtime error due to unsupported type conversion. Conversion of parameters is the responsibility of a JDBC Driver. At least in case of the Microsoft JDBC Driver, where parameter sendStringParametersAsUnicode is used to control that. Although, this is all or nothing proposition, and in case sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true (default) and the underlying column type is VARCHAR without a UTF8 collation, it does lead to full table scans.
